# How to pick rows in a 2d Numpy array and store into another so that one array keeps the rows with the highest values in a given column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a series of Numpy 2d arrays with a few columns and thousands of rows each.

The first column has a "quality" value for the row.

I also have an empty 2d Numpy array with 50 rows and same number of columns of the arrays above.

I'd like to iterate over these 2d arrays and select into this second array the values with the highest quality value, so that at the end the second array has the rows with the highest quality from all the initial 2d arrays.

For example:

```
arrays = [
    np.array([[10, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1]]),
    np.array([[1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [200, 1, 1, 1]]),
    np.array([[1, 2, 2, 2], [40, 1, 1, 1], [30, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1]]),
    np.array([[300, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1]]),
]

best_arrays = np.zeros((2, 4), dtype=np.int)

for i in range(len(arrays)):
   arr = arrays[i]

   # do something so that the rows with highest quality are selected into the `best_arrays` array

   print(best_arrays)
```

So in that the loop would print:

```
>> [[10, 2, 2, 2], [3, 1, 1, 1]]  # best rows of first array
>> [[10, 2, 2, 2], [200, 1, 1, 1]]  # best rows between first and second arrays
>> [[40, 2, 2, 2], [200, 1, 1, 1]]
>> [[300, 2, 2, 2], [200, 1, 1, 1]]  # best_arrays has the rows with highest "quality" of all.
```

How can I do this in Numpy? These arrays have a very large number of rows so I can't just iterate over in pure python - I'm looking for a Numpy function so that it runs in C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that the number of rows are in thousands (which is not that bad), I think this approach will be fairly efficient and flexible to pick the needed number of best rows from each 2D array.

```py
best = 2
quality_col = 0
for array in arrays:
# sort the rows based on the "quality" column
     print(array[np.flip((array[:, quality_col].argsort()))][:best, :])
```

### Output

```sh
[[10  1  1  1]
 [ 3  1  1  1]]
[[200   1   1   1]
 [  1   1   1   1]]
[[40  1  1  1]
 [30  1  1  1]]
[[300   2   2   2]
 [  3   1   1   1]]
```

Comment: Ah, good method.. I can actually "select" the best rows for each array and then concatenate the next array to it, and select again. Repeating this process will get the top quality rows overall.

Comment: Yes that is possible and is actually good idea than to first concatenate all 2D arrays and find the best overall. Cause with many thousands of rows sorting would take longer .

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example derived from @sai's answer with that last step to concatenate arrays and pick the best ones:

```
import numpy as np

arrays = [
    np.array([[10, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1]]),
    np.array([[1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [200, 1, 1, 1]]),
    np.array([[1, 2, 2, 2], [40, 1, 1, 1], [30, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1]]),
    np.array([[300, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1], [3, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1]]),
]

best_arrays = np.zeros((0, 4), dtype=np.int64)

best = 2
quality_col = 0
for i in range(len(arrays)):
   best_arrays = np.vstack((best_arrays, arrays[i]))

   # select the best rows
   best_arrays = best_arrays[np.flip((best_arrays[:, quality_col].argsort()))][:best, :]

print(best_arrays)
```

And the best ones are selected:

```
[[300   2   2   2]
 [200   1   1   1]]
```